# Throwing 404 Error with message "Cannot POST /api/users/register"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

The main problem is here --> cant go through proxy - don't know why
gave all the routes and checked them correctly
but overall still not working
Even though I can use cors and try directly but not sure why cant I use this method to perform the action ?

I am trying to register the user and send the data to MongoDB but it is not allowing it ?
can you please give a suggestion?
thanks

````
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/register 404 (Not Found)
 Error: Request failed with status code 404
     at createError (createError.js:16)
     at settle (settle.js:17)
     at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
 ```
 
 frontend part- I am using for react 
 
 ```import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 
 import axios from "axios";
 import Error from "../components/Error";
 import Loader from "../components/Loader";
 import Success from '../components/Success'
 export default function Registerscreen() {
   const [name, setname] = useState("");
   const [email, setemail] = useState("");
   const [password, setpassword] = useState("");
   const [cpassword, setcpassword] = useState("");
   const[loading, setloading]=useState(false)
   const[error, seterror]=useState(false)
   const[success, setsuccess]=useState(false) 
   async function register(){
 
       if(password!=cpassword)
       {
           alert("passwords not matched")
       }
       else{
           const user={
               name,
               email,
               password
           }
           
           try {
             setloading(true)
             const result = await axios.post('/api/users/register',user)
             setloading(false)
             setsuccess(true)
             setemail('')
             setname('')
             setcpassword('')
             setpassword('')
           } catch (error) {
             seterror(true)
             setloading(false)
             console.log(error);
           }
       
       }
 
   }
 
   return (
     <div className='register'>
       <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5">
         <div className="col-md-5 mt-5 text-left shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
 
           {loading && (<Loader/>)}
           {success && (<Success success='User Registered Successfully' />)}
           {error && (<Error error='Email already registred' />)}
 
           <h2 className="text-center m-2" style={{ fontSize: "35px" }}>
             Register
           </h2>
           <div>
             <input required type="text" placeholder="name" className="form-control mt-1" value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setname(e.target.value)}} />
             <input required type="text" placeholder="email" className="form-control mt-1" value={email} onChange={(e)=>{setemail(e.target.value)}} />
             <input
               type="text"
               placeholder="password"
               className="form-control mt-1"
               value={password}
               required
               onChange={(e)=>{setpassword(e.target.value)}}
             />
             <input
               type="text"
               placeholder="confirm password"
               className="form-control mt-1"
               value={cpassword}
               required
               onChange={(e)=>{setcpassword(e.target.value)}}
             />
             <button onClick={register} className="btn btn-primary rounded-pill mt-3 mb-3">REGISTER</button>
             <br/>
             <a style={{color:'black'}} href="/login">Click Here To Login</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
 ```
 pacakage.json- where I gave a proxy and trying to make it work
 ```,
   "browserslist": {
     "production": [
       ">0.2%",
       "not dead",
       "not op_mini all"
     ],
     "development": [
       "last 1 chrome version",
       "last 1 firefox version",
       "last 1 safari version"
     ]
   },
   "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
 }
 ```
 
 usersroute- defined all the routes 


 ```const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
 // express router 
 const User = require("../models/user")
 //import the user model 
 
 router.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
   
 
     const newUser = new User({name: req.body.name , email: req.body.email , password: req.body.password})
 
     try {
         const user = await newUser.save()
         // save the user 
         res.send('User Registered successfully')
     } catch (error) {
          return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
     }
 
 });
 
 
 router.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
 
     const {email , password} = req.body
 
     try {
         
         const user = await User.findOne({email : email , password: password})
         // match the subset in a collection 
 
         if(user){
        
             res.send(currentUser);
         }
         else{
             return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User Login Failed' });
         }
 
     } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Something went weong' });
     }
   
 });
 
 
 
 
 
 
 module.exports = router
 ```
 
 
 server.js---- server file where I gave all the routes 
 ```
 const express = require("express");
 
 const app = express();
 
 
       bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
 // support parsing of application/json type post data
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
 //support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 
 
 
 const dbConfig = require('./db')
 app.use(express.json())
 // import the rooms route 
 const roomsRoute = require('./routes/roomsRoute')
 const usersRoute = require('./routes/usersRoute')
 
 
 
 // access for the rooms route- to go and check the endpoints in rooms route- to fecth the rooms in database 
 app.use('/api/rooms', roomsRoute)
 app.use('api/users', usersRoute)
 
 
 const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 
 app.listen(port,() => console.log(`yayay Server running on port ${port}`));
 
 
 
 
 ```
 Userschema
 ```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     name : {
         type: String , 
         required: true
     },
     email : {
         type: String , 
         required: true
     },
     password : {
         type: String , 
         required: true
     },
     isAdmin : {
         type: Boolean  , 
         default: false
     }
 
 } , {
     timestamps : true,
     collection: 'users',
 })
 
 const userModel = mongoose.model('users', userSchema)
 module.exports = userModel
 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is a configuration error or it is because of the proxy.

There is an error in your server.js file, where you mentioned the route request.

Please change the route to

```
app.use('/api/users', usersRoute)
```

instead of this

```
app.use('/api/rooms', roomsRoute)
app.use('api/users', usersRoute)
```

then the link the your trying to get will be passed as a post request to the back-end.

404- is syntax error. I would start by checking the syntax rather than the config file.

Comment: all good , happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You've configured the API server to use port **5000** by default, and the frontend app is calling port **3000**.

Make sure you're calling the API via the correct port number.

- You can also try to change the API to a full URL if it's a proxy
  issue, like this

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/users": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
},
```

- Or if you're using `webpack`, make sure you configure the proxy correctly.
  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

Comment: i am not using webpack

Comment: I tried to change the full url but it is asking to use cors

Comment: @ganguly yes, you'd need to configure your server to enable cors - https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: tried using this ```"proxy": {
    "/api/users": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
}, but same error

Comment: wanted to know why it is not accepting this way???

Comment: maybe it's related to this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103

Comment: When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string.

Comment: this the error i got when i tried to use ur code?